# Why ‘add’ instruction is not executed for static variables?

Tags: c, assembly

This is an assembly / c question.

I have this simple C program:

```
main ()
{
  register int i = 0;
  register int c = 0;
  static int A[5]= {1,2,3,4,5}; 

  Loop: c=c+A[i];
  i=i+1;
  if (i!=5) goto Loop;
}
```

First I compile this program and run debugging by using gdbtui, then with display/I $pc to track details. I see that the add instruction is executed for `c=c+A[i];`  But I see ‘add’ instruction is executed for `i=i+1`;

Why is that?

--- EDIT ---

To clarify:

I debug this step by step as shown below, and my question is why I see This i=i+1; is executed by not c=c+A[i];.

```
Breakpoint 1, main() at loop.c:3
register int i = 0;
(gdb) step
i=i+1;
(gdb) step
if (i!=5) goto Loop;
(gdb) step
i=i+1;
(gdb) step
if (i!=5) goto Loop;
```

I was expecting here something like:

(gdb) step

c=c+A[i];

Comment: Paul Evans > My question is about static variable than code optimization :)

Comment: So, you see addition both for i and A[i], what is the problem? Post Assembly code and ask exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: So I see an execution of 'add $0x1, $ebx' for i=i+1;  but I dont see anything for c=c+A[i];

Comment: @user2735745: how are we supposed to help you if you don't post the whole assembly listing?

Comment: Which architecture are you talking about?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: This is Intel

Comment: Just edited my question with some clarifications

Comment: Intel uses at least 4 different architectures.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Intel Core i5 CPU, M460 @ 2.53GHz

Comment: Edit again, my big mistake,  static int A[] is static.

Comment: So, Intel 64 then? Or IA-32?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: 64 I belive: http://ark.intel.com/products/50179/Intel-Core-i5-460M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_53-GHz

Comment: That CPU supports both architectures. What does your compiler say?

Comment: @Nik Bougalis: I have a school project to find out where Static array data is stored, when it is created and how/when executed, and I was given this program as an example that can help me to answer the question.

Comment: @kull ... I see... but for the record, it's unclear to me how this program (or your particular approach) could help you do that.

Comment: @Nik Bougalis: as it was told me, the fact that 'c=c+A[i];' is not executed when I call a next step is a key to the problem.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I cannot find that out, I have not enough coding skills :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to be an optimisation from the compiler, as the c varibale is never used and c is static, it is not present in the final program.

try

```
return c;
```

and you will see

```
c= c+A[i];
```

in gdb

or try to change

```
int static A
```

to to

```
int A
```

and it will works too

Comment: You are correct, adding return c; makes that the line c= c+A[i]; in gdb is executed.  Please explain me, why also removing 'static' from A will do the same?

Comment: to be honest, I really don't know why it behaves like that